# Supporting hyperplane of convex function

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Below is the appendix B of Evan's PDE book on supporting hyperplanes of convex functions.

[image]

In the remark (1), he says that the mapping $y\to f(x)+r\cdot(y-x)$ determines the supporting hyperplane to f at x. But,I am thinking that shouldn't the map be defined as $x\to f(x)+r\cdot(y-x)$ not from $y$ as x is the point of "tangency"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Evans means that a supporting hyperplane at $ (x, f(x)) $ is the graph of the mapping $ y \mapsto f(x) + r\cdot (y - x) $.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood what he meant :(